# why can't I convert a lambda to a std::function here?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I need a function that generates other functions. Why doesn't the following not let me convert a `lambda` to a `std::function`? I've done that before.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<int()> funcGen(int param) {
    std::function<int()> myGeneratedFunc = 
    [param](int input) -> int { 
        return input+param;
    };
    return myGeneratedFunc;
}

int main() {

    std::function<int()> myFunc = funcGen(3);
    std::cout << "this should be 4=3+1: " << myFunc(1) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

On [ideone](https://ideone.com/QXoRev) I get the following error:

```
error: conversion from ‘funcGen(int)::<lambda(int)>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<int()>’ requested
```

Comment: On which line? From main, or from the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::function<int()>` accepts a function which takes in no arguments and returns an `int`. Your proposed lambda takes in an `int` and returns an `int`.

Consider `std::function<int(int)>` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<int(int)> funcGen(int param) {
    std::function<int(int)> myGeneratedFunc = 
    [param](int input) -> int { 
        return input+param;
    };
    return myGeneratedFunc;
}

int main() {

    std::function<int(int)> myFunc = funcGen(3);
    std::cout << "this should be 4=3+1: " << myFunc(1) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```